# What does 追行叙功奖励 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

我正在查“追叙”的意思，在以下网站查到了词义

https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%BF%BD%E5%8F%99/351020?fr=aladdin

> 追叙，读音为zhuī xù，汉语词汇，释义为追行叙功奖励

“追行叙功奖励”到底是什么意思？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

追 = 追溯 = trace

行 = 行為 = action

叙 = 叙述 = recount

功 = 功勞 = contribution

奖励 = reward

追行叙功奖励 = trace one's action and recount his contributions for reward

Answer (score 0):

追行: 跟踪寻找

叙功: 评定功劳等级次序

追行叙功奖励 means 跟踪寻找, 评定功劳，并给予奖励.

Answer (score 0):

It means to trace who did good thing and reward them.

According to dictionary owned by Ministry of Education in Taiwan.

[追](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000008095) can mean:

> 回溯已往。

(Think or deal with something retrospectively.)

[行](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000007256) can mean:

> 做、從事。

(Do something.)

敘功獎勵 means reward those who did good thing.

According to dictionary owned by Ministry of Education in Taiwan.

[敘功](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000111578) can means:

> 評定功勛。

(Evaluate the contribution to stabilize country.)

獎勵 can mean:

> 獎賞勉勵。

(Reward and encouragement.)